# kernel /proc/pid/stack format, what does the addresses mean?

Tags: process, linux-kernel, stack, procfs

given a stack like the following:

```
cat /proc/17019/stack
[<0>] futex_wait_queue_me+0xc4/0x120
[<0>] futex_wait+0x10a/0x250
[<0>] do_futex+0x325/0x500
[<0>] SyS_futex+0x13b/0x180
[<0>] do_syscall_64+0x73/0x130
[<0>] entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x3d/0xa2
[<0>] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

take the line `futex_wait_queue_me+0xc4/0x120` as an example, what does 0xc4 and 0x120 mean?

and additionally, how can I figure out the line of code corresponding to this address?

Comment: Use addr2line to get line number

Answer (score 2):

`futex_wait_queue_me+0xc4/0x120` - In call stack at this function current operation is at offset `0xc4` and total size of the function is `0x120`, both are in hexadecimal format. For Kernel subroutines, you can get the corresponding line by using objdump of vmlinux provided it has debug symbols to map it.

As shown below in `system_call_fastpath`, current offset of `0x22` is actually `34d` in disassembled output.

```
[root@linux ~]# cat /proc/26581/stack
[<ffffffff9f28eace>] ep_poll+0x23e/0x360  
[<ffffffff9f28ff9d>] SyS_epoll_wait+0xed/0x120
[<ffffffff9f774ddb>] system_call_fastpath+0x22/0x27
[<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff

(gdb) disassemble system_call_fastpath
Dump of assembler code for function system_call_fastpath:
0xffffffff81774db9 <+0>:     cmp    $0x14c,%rax
0xffffffff81774dbf <+6>:     jae    0xffffffff81774f43 <badsys>
0xffffffff81774dc5 <+12>:    sbb    %rcx,%rcx
0xffffffff81774dc8 <+15>:    and    %rcx,%rax
0xffffffff81774dcb <+18>:    mov    %r10,%rcx
0xffffffff81774dce <+21>:    mov    -0x7e7fd6c0(,%rax,8),%rax
0xffffffff81774dd6 <+29>:    callq  0xffffffff81386770 <__x86_indirect_thunk_rax>
0xffffffff81774ddb <+34>:    mov    %rax,0x50(%rsp)
End of assembler dump.
(gdb)
```